# Why do my webapi request remain in a pending state after a browser refresh

Tags: asp.net, .net, asynchronous, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am encountering a very strange problem and I couldn't find anything about this online.
In the code I am writing I have a request to the database which takes a long time.
Like in the semi-pseudocode below.

The method I am calling is an action for a .NET framework WebAPI controller.
I am using .NET framework version 4.7.2

```cs
  

  static bool _isRefreshing = false;
    
    [HttpGet, Route("endpoint")]
    void EndpointContainingLongRunningMethod(){
    
        if (_isRefreshing) return ...msg...;
    
        _isRefreshing = true;
    
        ... 

        var task = new Task<resulttype>(()=>{

            using (var scon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (var scom = new SqlCommand()) {
    
                scom.Connection = scon;
                scom.CommandText = "HEAVY QUERY";
    
                using (var reader = scom.ExecuteReader()) {
    
                    while(reader.Read()) {
                    ...
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    
        _isRefreshing = false;
    
        return ...;
    }
```

The steps I take from the client are as followed:

1. I call the endpoint from the client
2. Every subsequent call will give me a message back saying that the request is still being handled if it hasn't finished.
3. I refresh the browser while it is still handling the request in the background.
4. Now when I try to make calls to the endpoint, no matter what method I call on the controller, all requests remain in a pending state until a given amount of time (this could be a simple internal timeout or until the job is fully handled, I am not sure about this).

Now given the above steps I am really puzzled, the problem only happens after I refresh the browser.
And the problem only happens due to the SqlReader.
I can confirm that the task is running on a different thread, the HttpContext.Current is empty within the task for example.

Things I've tried:

- Replacing the sqlreader with a Thread.Sleep(60000) (when I do this everything works without entering the pending state, even after browser refresh).
- I tried to not run the request Async, but simply provided a separate endpoint which first check whether or not the data has finished processing.
- I tried putting the request in a non-webapi class to see whether or not I am experiencing session locking due to the use of a session state.
- Setting the IIS application pool settings "Maximum worker processes" to 0.
- I've tried setting the Connection Pooling to false and true in the Connection String

I've searched a lot by google, and in stack overflow and I am completely puzzled.

My questions is, what could possibly be the cause of everything working 100% without a problem, but a browser refresh makes all subsequent requests pending instead of being handled (I've set a breakpoint, the pending state in this case is due to the endpoint not being hit at all until the "pending timeout" is over)?

Comment: Do you create/open a connection for every request in a middleware? Maybe it’s performed with your ORM

Comment: 1. Wrong understanding of multiple threads. Your `if-else` won't work without locks. 2. ASP.NET can generate multiple `HttpApplication` instances to handle incoming requests, so simple locks inside a method of a single instance becomes useless. 3. Changing "Maximum worker processes" only makes it worse, as that adds multiple processes into the picture. You might hire a mentor to study ASP.NET multithreading systematically, not from shattered pieces.

Comment: @BasilKosovan middlewares are netcore terminology this is .net framework.
Also note that I am using an SqlCommand which isn't an ORM.

Comment: @LexLi I'm not sure what you mean with point 1, I've tried several things.
2. Could you clarify this as well?
3. This was more of an I'm out of options to try out thing, let's see what this does thing.